# can you overwrite ros :: Timer to restart the counter?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I would like to restart an accountant if a circumstance

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/272916/can-you-overwrite-ros-::-timer-to-restart-the-counter?/) by [mag.rod](https://answers.ros.org/users/30299/mag.rod/) on ROS Answers with karma: 58 on 2017-10-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think a combination of `.stop()` and `.start()` would do what you want.

See also the [ros::Timer](http://docs.ros.org/kinetic/api/roscpp/html/classros_1_1Timer.html) docs.

Older question / duplicate: #q11308.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2017-10-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1